# Is there any suggestion on the database option to replace Firebase Firestore that can be work on Huawei devices? - Flutter

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

I am developing an application using Flutter and integrating some Huawei Kit into the application. My final aim is to deploy it into the Huawei App Gallary.

However, I am using Firebase Firestore Database as the database for my project previously. But it seems not to work on Huawei devices.

Is there any database option that can be used in the Flutter Project to replace the Firebase Firestore which can be used on Huawei devices?

Comment: check https://appwrite.io/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Huawei Cloud DB](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-base) as an alternative.

Huawei Cloud DB is a device-cloud synergy database product that provides data synergy management capabilities between the device and cloud, unified data models, and various data management APIs. In addition to ensuring data availability, reliability, consistency, and security, CloudDB enables seamless data synchronization between the device and cloud, and supports offline application operations, helping developers quickly develop device-cloud and multi-device synergy applications.

For details, You could follow [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-flutter-usage-0000001154073689) to integrate the Cloud DB plugin for Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try huawei CloudDB Service. Find the guides [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-introduction-0000001054212760).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).